# How to insert a white space before open bracket

Tags: r, string, gsub, regex-group

I have a string `3.4(2.5-4.7)`, I want to insert a white space before the open bracket "(" so that the string becomes `3.4 (2.5-4.7)`.

Any idea how this could be done in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- "3.4(2.5-4.7)"
sub("(.*)(?=\\()", "\\1 ", x, perl = T)
[1] "3.4 (2.5-4.7)"
```

This regex is based on *lookahead*: it creates one capturing group subsuming everything up until the lookahead, namely, the opening parenthesis (`?=\\()`), recalls it and inserts one whitespace after it in the replacement argument to `sub` (which is enough unless you have more than one such substitution per string, in which case `gsub`is needed). The argument `perl = T`needs to be added to enable the lookahead.

**EDIT**:

If you have a string like this:

```
x <- "3.4(2.5to4.7)"
```

the regex gets slightly more complex; the underlying idea though remains the same: you divide the string into different captruing groups `(...)`, which you then recall using appropriate backreference in the replacement argument while adding the sought spaces:

```
sub("(.*)(\\(\\d+\\.\\d+)(to)(\\d+\\.\\d+\\))", "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4", x)
[1] "3.4 (2.5 to 4.7)"
```

**EDIT2**:

```
x <- '3.4(2.5,4.7)'
sub("(.*)(\\(\\d+\\.\\d+)(,)(\\d+\\.\\d+\\))", "\\1 \\2\\3 \\4", x)
[1] "3.4 (2.5, 4.7)"
```

**EDIT3**:

```
x <- '3(2,4)'
sub("(.*)(\\(\\d+)(,)(\\d+)", "\\1 \\2\\3 \\4", x)
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to address all variants you have mentioned in the comments. Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Your EDIT and EDIT2 worked well for `x <- '3.4(2.5,4.7)'`, but they did not work when `x <- '3(2,4)'`. It seems that numbers within parenthesis are required to have at least 1 digit. Is there any solution when numbers are integers?

Comment: I tried sub("(.*)(\\(\\d+\\.*\\d*)(to)(\\d+\\.*\\d+\\))", "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4", a) and it seemed to work. Substituting + with * allows for matching at least 0 times rather than at least 1 time. Please let me know if I am anywhere wrong. Thx.

Comment: Please see new edit. What exactly is your question regarding this code of yours: `sub("(.*)(\(\\d+\\.*\\d*)(to)(\\d+\\.*\\d+\))", "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4", a)`? Another thing: which of the answers **really**, or at least **most closely**, answers your question?

Comment: I tried `sub("(.*)(\(\\d+\\.*\\d*)(to)(\\d+\\.*\\d+\))", "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4", a)` to solve the issue `x <- '3(2to4)'` cannot be adequately separated by space following the EDIT. Your EDIT3 solved this issue, while `sub("(.*)(\(\\d+\\.*\\d*)(to)(\\d+\\.*\\d+\))", "\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4", a)` may be directly used for both integers and numbers with digits. Sorry for my ambiguity. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
gsub('(.*)(\\(.*\\))', '\\1 \\2', '3.4(2.5-4.7)')
#[1] "3.4 (2.5-4.7)"
```

The way the regex works is that it creates two groups. The first group `(.*)` it takes all elements and the second group `(\\(.*\\))` takes all elements after the parenthesis. Note that we need to escape the parenthesis so we use `\\(`. We then join those two groups with a space between them `\\1 \\2`

Comment: Thanks Sotos. That worked perfectly. May I ask for the meaning of . * \\ and why they are enclosed in brackets. Any suggested website is also welcome. regex has been troubling me for a long time but I have not yet known how best to get started.

Comment: I added some  explanation.

Comment: What about converting '3.4(2.5to4.7)' to '3.4 (2.5 to 4.7)' ? In addition to adding space before parenthesis, I also need space before and after "to". An what if converting '3.4(2.5,4.7)' to '3.4 (2.5, 4.7)' ? Sorry for these separate question in old thread. Thx

Answer (score 2):

A very short way uses `sub`, which will substitute the first open bracket `(` with a space followed by an open bracket, i.e.  `(`.

```
x <- '3.4(2.5-4.7)'
sub("\\(", " (", x)
# [1] "3.4 (2.5-4.7)"
```

Alternatively, you can specify the argument `fixed = TRUE` which considers the pattern as fixed and not as a regular expression.

```
x <- '3.4(2.5-4.7)'
sub("(", " (", x, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "3.4 (2.5-4.7)"
```